# How do I get a query of clients with many contact numbers? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have 2 tables, clients and contact numbers. Each client has one or many contact number, its a one to many relationship. And I need to make an excel document that for each row it has one client and its contact numbers. For example:

client name | contact_number_1 | contact_number_2| ...

I want to make it in POSTGRESQL to be fast. Doesn't matter the way that I make the excel file. I just need the query to make the rest.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can parse the result and create the Excel file from there, the most flexible solution is to aggregate the numbers into an array:

```
select c.client_id,
       c.client_name,
       array_agg(cn.number) as contact_numbers
from client c
  join concat_number cn on cn.client_id = c.client_id
group by c.client_id, c.client_name;
```

Another alternative is to use `string_agg(cn.number, ',')` to get a comma-separated list (but the array is more robust against embedded commas in the names).

If you really do need to get the numbers in separate columns, you need to decide on a sensible upper limit of columns, then you can use the first query and extract the array elements as columns:

```
select client_id, 
       client_name, 
       contact_numbers[1] as contact_number_1,
       contact_numbers[2] as contact_number_2,
       contact_numbers[3] as contact_number_3,  
       ... 
from (      
  select c.client_id,
         c.client_name,
         array_agg(cn.number) as contact_numbers
  from client c
    join concat_number cn on cn.client_id = c.client_id
  group by c.client_id, c.client_name
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a dynamic number of columns returned, it gets a bit complicated cause you have to know the maximum number of columns for the returned results, or you hard-code a set number for the highest number you think will exist.

If you can live with having one column represent all of the possible contacts, then you can aggregate them all into a single column:

```
select c.clientName, STRING_AGG(COALESCE(con.contact_number,''),'|') as contact_numbers
from clients c
left join contacts con on c.clientId = con.clientId
group by c.clientName
order by c.clientName
```